# Manually save full fragment back stack state in Android fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I currently have an activity with 2 panels and a stack of fragments on each panel with also nested fragments inside. Everything is nicely saved and restored by FragmentActivity (support library) however, since i need to do some heavy task during onCreate() this create some lag.

The fragments in the task depend on the heavy task so i cannot create the fragments before doing the task. So, question is, is there any smart way to save the entire back stack and restore it after onCreate is called? I know i can save a single fragment state but i need to store the entire stack and restore it as it is on the correct view containers.

Full back stack means all the Fragments i have in FragmentManager.backStack()
Heavy Task means something i cannot do on the onCreate() method because it takes more than 5 seconds.

Comment: define "full backstack state" and "heavy task"

Comment: but with assumption that heavy task download and prepare data and full backstack state means cache the data then you could create child fragment without view, also set that it could be retained ... do the task there and store the data as fragment's field ... obtain the retained instance of this child fragment inside parent fragment ... and ... to long to write ...

Comment: @Selvin the FragmentManager BackStack entries, how else should i describe it? And Heavy Task is also pretty clear, anything that takes some time should not be done during onCreate(), thought it was quite obvious. Edited the question.

Comment: @Selvin i cannot do that, i have not one fragment, i have many fragments and they cannot restore their view state without the task output

Comment: then no, you can't do this ... just think if task takes so much time and have to be done then ...

Comment: @Selvin why? FragmentActivity.onCreate() does exactly this but its using internal methods. I could go through the backstack and save each state one by one and then create it again, so its possible, i just dont know if there is a smart way or something already done.